# blocking UI while loading static C++ library in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk

My UI thread is blocking, while I'am loading static C++ library.
I want to create a spinning loading bar, so user don't think App is freezed. But my bar is not spinning due to this library loading(it takes like 5 seconds). Is it possible to load library in static block and not update UI?

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /**
     * Load native libraries
     */

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", Activity.RESULT_OK);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should loading your "native-lib" in a non-main thread.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
static {
  new Thread(() -> {        
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
    }
  }).start();
}
```

But you have to care about waiting until the library is loaded and initialized before using it.

Comment: This is a good and easy fix. But even then, using a heavy native library directly from an Activity is not a good idea. It's safer to wrap the **native-lib** in a separate Java class that is not managed by Android lifecycle.

Comment: Right - it's not a very 'clean' solution. But honestly i can't really see how using a seperate class would improve runtime behaviour. Can you explain that?

Comment: A separate class can be loaded in a more controlled manner. For Activity, it's totally system's responsibility. You don't know when Android will instantiate it. Especially for the example provided by the OP, this **LoadingActivity**'s sole purpose is to load the native library. The huge overhead (memory, resources, maintenance) is not justified.

Comment: Another good reason to avoid native methods in Android Framework-derived classes (Application, Activity, Fragment, *etc*.) is to allow automated testing, with tools like Robolectric (see https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1171).